# Clear used RAM for Tkinter TEXT widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, textbox

In my GUI I create a ttk.notebook and then put Text widgets into each tab and dump logs/info into these Text widgets. If the process is restarted with a new set of log files I `.forget()` the old tabs and then create the new ones. I've noticed that the ram used from the original Text widgets is not cleared when I do this. How can I free this ram?

Example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook
main = Tk()
def maker():
    nb = Notebook(main, name='nbook')
    nb.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
    frame1 = Frame(name='frame1')
    txt = Text(frame1, wrap=NONE)
    txt.grid()
    nb.add(frame1, text='textwindow')
    txt.insert('end', 'hello\n' * 1000000)

def remover():
    print(main.winfo_children())
    for tab in main.children['nbook'].tabs():
        main.children['nbook'].forget(tab)
    print(main.winfo_children())

b1 = Button(main, text='Insert', command=maker)
b1.grid(row=1, column=0)
b2 = Button(main, text='Clear tabs', command=remover)
b2.grid(row=1, column=1)
main.mainloop()
```

In the example, when you click "Insert" it creates the widget and dumps a bunch of text into it. If you call remover with the "Clear tabs" button it forgets all tabs but the ram used by that text is never free. Even if you destroy the text widget the ram is not released. How can I free this up?

Comment: Long story short - it's a known "bug" and you can do nothing about it.

Comment: @CommonSense I have the same issue, there are some updates about this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later found that just doing a `.forget()` on the tabs does not get rid of the memory used by the widgets. This may be because they are referenced somewhere else but I couldn't find the source. If I `.destroy()` the widgets from the tab before doing the `.forget()` on the tab itself then the memory is eventually freed by garbage collector. For my situation, running a new set of logs through the tool reuses the currently used memory and the extra(if any) is freed after it sits for a bit.

Answer (score 2):

```
Text.delete('1.0', END)
Text.edit_reset()
```

Will clear the history of the Text widget, so call this after delete.
Hope this solves your problem

Comment: By doing this and then destroying im actually seeing a 2MB increase in ram used instead of any drop.

Answer (score 1):

Destroying entire (set of) widget(s) when you only need to configure one of their attributes sounds like a very poor design, and such practice is notorious for resulting in pricey memory leaks, as you have already seen.

In any case, I reckon you would be much better off by simply configuring the widgets you already have, as opposed to destroying/recreating them when the changes are due.

From what I've been able to comprehend, you said you need to frequently display some text (namely, logs?) in the `Text` widget, so why not just clear the text you already have and insert the new one into the widget:

```
txt.delete('1.0', 'end') # clearing the text widget
txt.insert('end', my_log) # inserting the log into the text widget
```

Comment: Is doing a .forget() on a tab the same as destroying? Each time a set of logs is parsed a different amount of tabs are created. If the second time only needs 2 tabs but 9 are shown I would still have 7 tabs that need to be removed because they arent being used. Additionally, if you delete all the text from a Text widget it does not free the used ram. So if one set of logs used 2 GB of ram and the next uses 500MB of ram the application is still holding onto 2GB of ram from before. That is the memory that im trying to free up.

Comment: Does this give you memory leaks? `tkinter.tk.call(widget, 'delete', index1, index2)`?

Comment: if I use 1.0 and END for the indexes this deletes all the text in the Text widget but the used memory does not change. Same as doing txt.delete('1.0', 'end'). I think thats what you were after.